# How can I place objects randomly in a cell for a 2D array based game? Java

Tags: java, arrays, random, multidimensional-array

Here I'm asked to do a method for the game which randomly places monsters in a map.. Im not really sure to start and **how can I place an object (ex.Boss) in cell (0,0) using nested for loops for the 2D array** Or randomly place the weak foes.
How to translate this idea into a code?

public void generateMap(ArrayList weakFoes, ArrayList strongFoes): //It should generate the whole map grid randomly. It should be ﬁlled with:

• 1 Boss: A random boss should be positioned in the top left of the map i.e. cell (0,0).

• 15 Weak Foes: The weak foes should be **randomly** positioned on the map. The weak foes should be chosen randomly from the input weakFoes.

Any help is appreciated.. Thank youu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the start of the method use this on both arraylists

```
Collections.shuffle(strongFoes);
Collections.shuffle(weakfoes);
```

both lists will now be randomized and you can add them normally to cells using a for loops like

```
int i monsterCount = 0;
map[0][0].add(strongFoe.get(0);
for(int i = 0; i<mapWidth; i++)
{
  for(int j = 0; i<maplength; j++)
  {
    map[i][j].add(weakfoe.get(monsterCount));
    monsterCount++;
  }

}
```

then all you need to do is base your logic around how often you want to add them, a more efficient way for the strongFoe would be to just Math.rand() and get the element at that index but simplicity sake I used the same method for both. The above code will change depending on what strucutres you are suing but the logic should be sound.

In reread the original question and see you only want it to happen 15 times so instead of the looping i have above I would have one loop that
loops to 15 generates two random numbers as the map co-ords and puts the monster in that square (unless a monster is already in it then pick another)